# Generate signature in Elixir and PHP using hmac

Tags: php, elixir, hmac

I try to generate a signature using Elixir, which has a same value as PHP does.

For example the code in PHP is

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", "abc", "def"));
```

and the output will be

`Mzk3ZjQ2NzM0MWU0ZDc4YzQ3NDg2N2VmMzI2MWNkYjQ2YzBlMTAzNTFlOWE5ODk5NjNlNmNiMmRjZTQwZWU1ZA==`

How should I generate the signature that has the same value in Elixir. I tried something like below

```
iex(9)> :crypto.hmac(:sha256, "abc", "def") |> Base.encode64                          │
"IOvA8JNERwE081BA9j6pix2OQUISlJ7lxQBCnRXqsIE="

iex(10)> :crypto.hash(:sha256, :crypto.hmac(:sha256, "abc", "def")) |> Base.encode64  │
"dxGiPN6KqBJrtS2wlC4tnJXwUsWf4u1LPDtDFK+VT5A="
```

or I switch the position of `abc` and `def`

```
iex(11)> :crypto.hash(:sha256, :crypto.hmac(:sha256, "def", "abc")) |> Base.encode64  │
"b+3P5oHu8e6HIlJe2MzcGhKm7tCcF/NE5wPIbEhrFGU="

iex(12)> :crypto.hmac(:sha256, "def", "abc") |> Base.encode64                         │
"OX9Gc0Hk14xHSGfvMmHNtGwOEDUempiZY+bLLc5A7l0="
```

But none of them has the same value. Can someone tell me how to do it the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that `hash_hmac` returns a hex string, while `:crypto.hmac` returns a binary.

The equivalent code in Elixir is:

```
iex(1)> :crypto.hmac(:sha256, "def", "abc") |> Base.encode16 |> String.downcase |> Base.encode64
"Mzk3ZjQ2NzM0MWU0ZDc4YzQ3NDg2N2VmMzI2MWNkYjQ2YzBlMTAzNTFlOWE5ODk5NjNlNmNiMmRjZTQwZWU1ZA=="
```

We need to use `String.downcase` because `Base.encode16` returns a hex string with capital `A-F` while PHP's `hash_hmac` returns lower case `a-f`.

Comment: After check out the document, I found out I can do it like `...|> Base.encode16(case: :lower) |> Base.encode64` without `String.downcase`